# EF4 to a dataset? And other pivot table madness

Tags: t-sql, entity-framework-4, pivot

The short question is: How do I handle a pivot table in EF4?  Any suggestions other than "pivot client-side" will be considered helpful.

One idea is to directly query the database and put the results into a dataset.  That's not a very gentlemanly solution.  My only other idea is to use some reflection magic of some sort to dynamically create properties for a temporary object.  I have no idea how to handle that in the View.

Here's the longer explanation and whatnot:

My application has pieces of equipment.  It allows the user to "claim" a piece of equipment, and then set a status for that piece of equipment.

The relevant table structure looks like:

```
    EquipmentId, EquipmentName, etc
    ClaimId, StatusChangeId, EquipmentId, UserId
    StatusChangeId, StatusId, etc
    StatusId, StatusName, etc
```

My query looks up all of the relevant claims for the user (not removed
or archived or new, only ones with statuses set), gets the latest status for each one, tallies them up, and then associates them with their respective equipment.

This big ass dynamic query pivots the data to create a resultset like:

```
equipment name    Total    Status1  Status2  Status 3
Computer            4         0        3        1
Monitor             6         1        5        0
```

The problem is...how do i handle that in EF4?  There is no
clean solution, obviously, because the Statuses are dynamic and being returned as
columns.  Which means the object would have to magically create
properties on the fly.  The statuses are not likely to change in the next few weeks, so as an
interim solution I've force fed it an object with the statuses
hardcoded.  But that is hideously ugly and kinda defeats the purpose of my
dynamic columns and, well, the entire Status table.

My only other idea is to take and split my beautiful new query that
takes less than a second to run against 1000+ records into a tiny
little query that gets the statuses and counts for a single piece of
equipment at a time and puts it all together in code.

For users that have a few hundred different types of equipment, that would mean a few hundred trips to the database.  And I have 2 other queries based on this one that go out and grab the equipment information for users that are associated with the base user...so if there is a user with a couple hundred types of equipment, and he is associated with two other users who have 70 types of equipment each, and they have users associated...you get the picture.

**Edit**

It occurs to me that this could potentially be solved by putting the columns into a list of a simple object with StatusName and Count as a part of a EquipmentStatus object.  Sadly, i still have no idea how to do the mapping.  [Even though Microsoft acknowledges that handling pivots is an issue, their official word is "we don't know when it'll happen".](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/632688/make-entity-framework-can-accommodate-dynamic-return-columns-from-store-procedure)

**EDIT 2**

As soon as I have time I will post my final solution. We are finally going to production this week, so it may be a few days.  Sorry anyone who comes here looking for an answer.

Comment: Two things: first, the "query pivots the data to create a table like" - actually a *resultset*, not a table; which leads on to: second, do you *need* **objects** in your clientside code, to hold the results of this pivot? Typically pivoting is done very close, if not immediately before, presenting results for output; if you don't need objects, just go directly to the store connection and run your sproc! I'm not sure what you mean by producing a dataset being "not a very gentlemanly solution" - what does that lack that you need?

Comment: Terminology corrected.  And I don't "need" the objects, but I'm irritated in general that EF4 is so bad at handling something like this.  The columns and the datatypes for their records are known to me, so I should be able to create a nested list of objects to handle the columns.  It's beginning to look like datasets are the only viable answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EF cannot handle such dynamic queries - EF is strongly typed so you need to have at least a type (class) having properties with the same name as columns in result set. This type can be used for materializing records from result set.

So how to use this approach with dynamic result set? It would require something like querying your database first to get names of columns used in your real query, using `Reflection.Emit` to create a dynamic assembly with dynamic type (a new one for every query with different result set) and use it in some dynamic way (probably by reflection).

> One idea is to directly query the database and put the results into a
>   dataset. That's not a very gentlemanly solution.

`DataSet`, `DataAdapter` and `DbCommand` are classes for queries with dynamic result sets. How are these classes worse than the solution with creating assemblies at runtime? DataSet will allow you implementing this in few minutes!

Comment: Pretty much nothing that I can think of is worse than using reflection to create types at runtime.  The biggest issue with using a raw dataset (besides ORM elitism) is that I've got to use other information contained in the Status table when I display, such as colors and whatnot.

Comment: Okay, so I used a dataset.  Because I have to use data from other tables, I created an object and populated it with data. I'm going to answer this myself in detail for anyone else who runs into this problem, but if it will let me I am going to accept yours as the answer since it started me down this path.

Comment: I don't think I agree that EF is incapable of this.  EF cannot do it out of the box, true.  If you are feeling brave, you could whip up a T4 template to produce, for instance, a list of dictionaries or even just a giant array.  This wouldn't really get you much over a DataSet, but it is should be possible to do it with EF.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question?  Do you mean how would you map the SP output into a list of dictionaries?

Comment: @TripleGilaman: Yes, how would you map SP result set into list of dictionaries by using EF?

Comment: I would have to hack a while to see what I could do, but it sounds like you believe this is a fool's errand?

Comment: @TripleGilaman: I'm afraid it would not work because whole EF's internal logic is based on strongly typed objects and reflection to fill them - the mapping just describes what properties should EF look for at runtime and there is no way to tell it to use some dictionary instead of strongly typed object.